# Sharepoint 2010 Analytics Report stopped working

Tags: 2010, web-analytics

I have setup the web analytics as mentioned in the documentation on MSDN and the reports were working fine initially but they have stopped working for the past 15 days. There were no changes made to the server configuration. I connected to the reporting database and was able to verify that data is being logged to the database. Am I missing something? I would really need a pointer on this !!!!

Answer (score 1):

The question is answered [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010setup/thread/30d11d27-6708-4bfe-a7d3-4b0aed522e7d).
Looks like the problem was caused by some of the updates to Sharepoint 2010